# Sublime text - shortcut for difftool

Tags: git, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I want to add a shortcut in order to launch difftool for current file.

I added to `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/UserDefault (Linux).sublime-keymap` the following entry:

```
[
  { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+g"], "command": "difftool" },
]
```

But it doesn't work.

I noticed that when I use the top menu (Tools->Git->This file->DiffTool) I  see the following command in sublime console:

```
['git', 'difftool', '--', 'path-to-file']
```

I wonder how should I write the shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Git` package adds items to the menu by providing a `Main.sublime-menu` file that lists the menu items that it wants to add and what commands to invoke when they're selected. This will tell you the `command` you need to use and also the `args` that you need to provide to get the same functionality.

The easiest way to do that is to use [PackageResourceViewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) to open the resource so you don't have to hunt down the file manually.

Based on this, the shortcut you want would look like this (although this is formatted to display nicer here and could be all one line, etc):

```
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+shift+g"],
    "command": "git_raw",
    "args": {
        "command": "git difftool",
        "append_current_file": true,
        "may_change_files": false
    }
}
```

If you don't already have existing key bindings, in order to use this you need to wrap the entire binding in a json array (`[` and `]`). Also note that all bindings need to be separated from each other with a comma.

Comment: Great! Just one small error - the whole hash should be wrapped with an array. Thanks!!!

Comment: True; this is meant to be just the single key binding itself, to be added to an existing key binds file.